# ESP-12f SoftwareSerial read fails

Tags: esp8266, softwareserial

I am trying to use esp8266 version of SoftwareSerial,  espsoftwareserial, on an esp-12f.

If I initialize an object using:

```
SoftwareSerial gpsSer(14,12, false, 256);
```

or

```
SoftwareSerial gpsSer(12,14, false, 256)
```

then gpsSer.write works in all both cases, using ports 12 and 14 for transmit appropriately,  but gps.read fails.

I would be grateful for any advice.

Paul

Comment: have you tried to use it with another serial device? You can even try to link it  to the hardware RX TX of esp to see if it behaves as expected.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the **full** code.

Comment: The sketch works fine if i use the hardware TX, RX I only use the RX port from the ESP to read the output of a GPS device which produces about 200 bytes per second